# Upgrade gradle 7.4 to 8.0-rc-1

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have update Gradle 7.4 to 8.0-rc-1 . Now I am getting warning
**Unable to decide if project isolation is enabled java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.gradle.internal.buildoption.BuildOption$Value org.gradle.api.internal.StartParameterInternal.getIsolatedProjects()'**
Build is successful how to avoid this warning.
I have added this below line
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-rc-1-bin.zip

Comment: If you want to use the RC version for Gradle, try upgrading your AGP plugin to 8.x as well.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/254049155